# useParams and useEffect, Parameter via ${id} in the useEffect function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

This is the code, I receive the id in the console but not the response from the firestore server

```
import Item from './Item'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {db} from "../Firebase"
import { collection, getDocs, query,} from "firebase/firestore";


const ContainerItems = () => {

    let idParam = useParams();
    const [ dataItem, setDataItem ] = useState([])


useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchData(){
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, `category/${(idParam)}/Items` )));
      let dataArray = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        dataArray.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
      });
      setDataItem(dataArray)
      console.log("Id",idParam)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [idParam])
    return (
        <>
            {dataItem.map((data)=>( 
                <Item item={data} key={data.id}/>
            ))}            
        </>
    )
}

export default ContainerItems;
```

the request to the server works, it just doesn't work when I add ${idParam}

Comment: What does the log statement say for idParam? I would expect it to be an object, in which case `category/${(idParam)}/Items` probably needs to be more like `category/${idParam.someParam}/Items`

Comment: const CategoryItem = ({ data }) => {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Image src={data.img} />
        <Info>
          <Title>{data.title}</Title>
          <Link to= {`/category/${data.id}`}>
            <Button>ENTER</Button>
          </Link>
        </Info>
      </Container>
    );
  };

export default CategoryItem,    ////it comes from here

Comment: It is from another request to Category

Comment: console.log("Id", idParam) = data.id 
effected by the previous onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `idParam` out of the object using destructuring.

```
let { idParam }  = useParams();
```

NOTE: Assuming you have named the path in the Route with the same name.

```
<Route path="/category/:idParam">...</Route>
```